# SQL Syntax Error Message

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to execute the following SQL queries on a database.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, ‘http://yourdomain’, ‘http://your-elastic-ip’) WHERE option_name = ‘home’ OR option_name = ‘siteurl';
```

I replace "yourdomain" with my domain, and I replace "your-elastic-ip" with my IP address on Amazon Web Services.  However, I keep getting an SQL syntax error.  It says:

```
WHERE option_name = ‘home’ OR option_name = ‘siteurl';

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE option_name = â€˜homeâ€™ OR option_name = â€˜siteurl'' at line 1.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Am I not understanding exactly what to put in the proper fields?  What am I supposed to replace "home" and "siteurl" with?

Comment: Looks like you copied from a page or file with a different character set.  You need to use single or double quotes to wrap the strings, as you can see at the end of the siteurl" <-- proper "

Comment: Curly quotes are evil. Kill them with fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What user2182349 is trying to say is: replace it with this:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://yourdomain', 'http://your-elastic-ip') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Notice how the single quotes are different. You have curly quotes, I've replaced them with straight ones, as MySQL doesn't recognise the curly ones. (You can see how it's interpreted them at the end of your error message).

Comment: The OP is using MySQL, not MS SQL Server, so your section about which versions it exists in is doubly irrelevant. Also, wrong, since it existed in [at least SQL Server 2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238479%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), and probably before that.

Comment: My apologies then. I took the quote about it only being available in those versions directly from the msdn site, without realising that the topic of the website was Transact-SQL. I have edited out the incorrect info.

Comment: MSDN articles generally list which versions of Microsoft products *the article refers to*, regardless of whether older products, or products from other vendors, support *the feature being described*.